# Wifi file transfer between Linux PC and Android

Tags: java, android, linux, ftp, wifi

Im thinking about my next project and I just wanted to know, what could be the simplest solution to implement.
I have a linux PC, that generates files (text files, images) and everytime the file is created, the PC should send it to my Android device via Wifi.
What could be the simplest solution? FTP? SSH?

I also want my custom Android app, so dont recommend me any kind of existing Android app, please.

Comment: HTTP and DNS-SD. But no clue how to open the port on the Android device.

Comment: Why not have the Android device pull the content from the server?

Answer (score 1):

There's a java http server available in a SINGLE FILE, and it supports posts and file-uploads: [nanoHTTPd](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/). On Linux, you can simply use curl to push the file to any http server. If you need to *find* your android device, you can use the excellent (and simple) [jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/).